# DAX/Power BI - Filter Two Unrelated Tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to filter a table based on another table, however there is not a direct relationship between the two. Here is the data model.
attr_Tkpr_vw contains all company employees, both current and historical.
attr_Time_vw contains date/time info.

My goal is to filter attr_Tkpr_vw for all employees between arbitrary hire and termination dates. These dates are supplied by a slicer based on the column attr_Time_vw[DateFull]

Here are my results. My slicer is set to dates between 1/1/2022 and 3/31/2022. When I put the measues "MinDate" and "MaxDate" into a vizualization I get the expected results. However, when I try and use these measures to filter attr_Tkpr the formula returns a table with ALL dates.

I'm clearly missing something key about how filter contexts work.

I have tried using the fuctions VALUES, SELECTEDVALUE, ALLSELECTED. None returns expected results.

Comment: Can you show the details via screenshots?

Comment: Negative, I don't have enough points to post screenshots. However I can link to a separate post which includes them. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Filter-Two-unrelated-Tables/m-p/2966417#M1014710

Comment: I checked the screenshot. It can be solved by using the measures and the Power BI Filters pane. Can you send the pbix file?